# Confusion about data frames and factors in R

Tags: r

I am a C programmer learning R.  I have read part of the 'R Cookbook' by Teetor and done some reading online.  I am having difficulty understanding data.frames in R.

I have a table in a file (i.e. test.dat)

```
Name Bill Judy Abe 
Age 32 45 67
SSN 5689 4212 6321
sex m f m
```

I read it in

```
data <- read.table("test.dat", header=TRUE)
```

I print out :

```
data[2,3]
```

And it returns :

```
[1] 4212
Levels: 4212 45 f
```

What are the levels and how can I stop it from printing this garbage?
Also, why can't I use the numeric value of `data[2,3]`?

E.g.

```
mode(data[2,3])
[1] "numeric"

data[2,3] * 5
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(data[2, 3], 5) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `data.frame`, values in a same column share a same variable type.
In this case, the sex row at the bottom is character, hence the entire column is interpreted as character(and converted to factor due to `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`).

Transpose your dat file so that Name, Age, SSN, and sex becomes the header.
Then Age and SSN columns are all numeric, so you can do mathematical calculation.

Comment: doing `data <- t(read.table("test.dat", header=TRUE))`. They are still factors and the header gets messed up.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: ```x <- t(read.table("test.txt", header = TRUE))```
```x <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)```
```names(x) <- x[1, ]```
```x[-1, ]```